# Task Tags in XSP sources

Tags: eclipse, xpages

In Java sources one can use (by default) //TODO, //FIXME and //XXX comments to add that part of source to Tasks view in Eclipse/Domino Designer.

I would like to use it in SSJS too, but I can't make it work. In Designer preferences **General/Editors/Structured Text Editors/Task Tags**, **Filters** tab, you can eneable "**Enable searching for Task Tags**" checkbox and tick XML type. Affected content types section contains "xsp" that is file extension of XP/CC sources.

But any tag in SSJS source (property of XML tag, actually) does not appear in Tasks view.

How to write such task tag into XP/CC source to make it work?

Comment: I didn't get the question. It works in XPages or custom controls (details explained here: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/hmedney/entry/using_the_eclipse_tasks_view_to_keep_track_of_to_dos_in_xpages_projects_in_domino_designer?lang=en)

Comment: But it doesn't work in SSJS. That's the question right?

Comment: Correct, you can comment XML by <!-- --> in source, and comments inside SSJS are ignored. And I am looking for solution for SSJS comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Domino Designer, searching for Task Tags can be enabled for most editors via the Preferences.
i.e. (General -> Editors -> Structured Text Editors -> Task Tags)

However, the reported behaviour occurs because the Task Tags are added to a CDATA section.

CDATA sections are basically the wild wild west of XML.

For reference, see http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-cdata-sect specifically:

"*Within a CDATA section, only the `]]>` string is recognized as markup, so that left angle brackets and ampersands may occur in their literal form; they need not (and cannot) be escaped using `&lt;` and `&amp;`*"

Therefore, for this reason, the contents of CDATA sections are generally ignored by Eclipse XML parsing and validating. So if `<!-- TODO -->` or `//TODO` (or any tag) is put into a CDATA section it is not picked up as such.

So as a consequence, any annotated Server-Side JavaScript in XSP source does not appear in the Tasks View.

Using this sample code as an example, the Tasks View displays as follows.

[image: Sample XSP code in the XPages Source View illustrating the use of Task Tags]
[image: Task Tags from sample XSP code appearing in the Tasks View in Domino Designer]