# TODO tag comments for SSJS in Xpages in Notes Version 9

Tags: xpages

At one of the Lotusspere sessions in Orlando, the //TODO comment tag was mentioned.  I thought that this was an extremely useful feature but sadly in looks to me like it does not work in SSJS?

[Task Tags in XSP sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13235349/task-tags-in-xsp-sources)

Any chance this has been fixed in version 9?   It does work in 8, but you need to place it outside your SSJS code block.

Comment: I would also be interested if there is a workaround in Notes 8 other than the one I mentioned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using the Domino Designer 9 beta build from December (the public beta). The Task Tags functionality still does **not** include TODO tags in SSJS script libraries and SSJS code blocks.

--

Do the following to control what contents the Tasks view shows:

- Choose the Configure Contents

  [image]
- Select "On any element in same project"
  [image]

You can do the same with the Problems view.

Comment: Curious that it works in CSJS script libraries but not SSJS libraries. Also the TODO view saldly shares the same issue as the error view, in that it shows items from all kind of databases.

Answer (score 1):

It may have been my session. It's standard Eclipse functionality, so only works in certain editors like the XML Editor. You may have hit the same gotcha I hit during preparation. Enabling it in the Tasks view is not enough. You need to enable it in the relevant editors in the Preferences. Open up preferences and type "Task" in the filter box. It should then get picked up from any SSJS in the source pane. It gets updated when the project is built.

Comment: Can you please be more specific?  I did as you suggested and I am not seeing any additional place to enable the todos.